# Union tested for current member in use

Tags: c++, variables, comparison, unions, members

Do unions have a control structure to test which member is currently in use (or if it has any at all)? I'm asking this because undefined behavior is never a good thing to have in your program.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, no such mechanism exists off-the-shelf. You'll have to take care of that yourself.
The usual approach is wrapping the `union` in a `struct`:

```
struct MyUnion
{
   int whichMember;
   union {
      //whatever
   } actualUnion;
};
```

So you have `MyUnion x;` and `x.whichMember` tells you which field of `x.actualUnion` is in use (you have to implement the functionality though).

Comment: +1:  This type of structure is often called either a "discriminated union" or a "tagged union".

Comment: Yes, I thought of a similar approach, but because I prefer language constructs to self-made ones I just had to know if one existed. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @AlexD. Pascal had a tagged union, but it amounted to the same thing as this. You still had to test the tag to determine which element was in use.