# Using unions and tags

Tags: c++, unions

How can we know whether the given input is int or char using unions in c++?

Please keep the program simple.

How can I actually know when the given input is char or int so that I perform specific operations?

I basically got to know that in a char array ,when I enter a double digits number,the array takes only the first digit,is there any correct method or I need to use only unions?

Comment: read input, parse input, if input looks like a number then treat it as a number.

Comment: @NathanOliver sir,can you please use unions and tell me.

Comment: There's no way to see which member of a union is currently in use. There's a simple work-around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035534/union-tested-for-current-member-in-use) called a tagged union, but you could also use a [`std::variant<int, char>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead of a union, which lets you check if it holds a type or not.

Comment: I guess you have a string input. If so, it is a char array. There are functions for detecting integer literals in strings (i.e. char arrays). In C/C++ unions do not contain any information about "which type they store". That way you can have a union over a float and a struct and be able to read mantissa and exponent, or you can have a union over a char and a packed struct of 8 1-bit fields and be able to read each the bits of a char separately, or a union over struct with packed char[4] or four chars and int (32bit), and read each byte of an int, without casting eacht. `union` is not `Either`.

Comment: a union wont help to detect of what type is some user input. A union can hold members of different types (actually only one of them at a given time), but to access them you need to choose which one to access by some other means

Answer (score 2):

Unions are not able to distinguish what type you put in. When it is important (what it is in most cases) and you don't want to the union as cast, then you need to store  what type of data you put in. 
E.g.,

```
typedef union
{
   int a;
   char b[4];
} myUn;
```

now you can do

```
myUn mu;
mu.a=42;
char c=mu.b[0];
```

and your compiler wont complain. So you need to store in a further location what type you have put in (if important).

e.g.,

```
typedef struct
{
   myUn mu;
   int type;
}
```

and encode in type what you have put in. But that is just a very basic solution and you should ask why you want to use a union here.